# Error in tapestry,i try to add 3 entites to one form

Tags: java, html, entity, tapestry

i have 3 entites Room(soba),Reservation and User,i want to add in reservation id koncert ,id user,and some string i have problem with add that.This is my cide.

```
public 
class RezervisanjeSobe {
@Inject
private RezervacijeDao rezervacijeDao;
  @SessionState
private User user;
@Inject
private SobeDao sobeDao;

@Inject
private SelectModelFactory smf;


@Property
private Rezervacije rezervacija;

@Property
private Rezervacije onerezervacija;

@Property
private List<Rezervacije> rezervacijeLista;

@Property
private List<Sobe> sobeLista;

@Property
private Sobe soba;

public void setupRender() {
    rezervacijeLista = rezervacijeDao.getListaRezervacija();
}

public SelectModel getSobaModel() {
    sobeLista = sobeDao.getListaSoba();
    return smf.create(sobeLista, "ime");
}


@CommitAfter
Object onSuccessFromRezervacijeForma() {
     rezervacija.setUserId(user)
    rezervacija.setSobaId(soba);
    rezervacijeDao.dodajRezervaciju(rezervacija);
    return this;
}

@CommitAfter
void onDelete(Integer id) {
    rezervacijeDao.obrisiRezervaciju(id);
}

public String getSobaIme() {
    if (onerezervacija.getSobaId() != null) {
        return onerezervacija.getSobaId().getIme();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
 }
    }`
```

And tml file:

```
        <html t:type="layout" title="Rezervisanje"
  t:sidebarTitle="Framework Version"
  xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd"
  xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">

<t:beaneditform t:id="rezervacijeForma" object="rezervacija" exclude="id" add="soba" >
    <p:soba>
        <t:label for="soba">Soba:</t:label>
        <t:select t:id="soba" model="sobaModel" value="soba" />
        <br/>
    </p:soba>
</t:beaneditform>

<t:grid source="rezervacijeLista" exclude="id" add="soba, delete" row="onerezervacija">        
    <p:sobaCell>
        ${sobaIme}
    </p:sobaCell>
    <p:deleteCell>
        <t:eventlink t:event="delete" context="onerezervacija">Delete</t:eventlink>
    </p:deleteCell>
</t:grid>
```

Error is about rezervacijeForma.
Tnx!

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: Error is about that @CommitAfter
Object onSuccessFromRezervacijeForma() is not public field.